# overwriting !important not possible

Tags: css

I am working on a form using Nintex / Sharepoint 2016 whereby I like to remove the scrollbars. When inspecting the css, this is what it shows:

[image]

I have tried implementing the following css to overwrite the overflow but I am not having any luck. 
Is there something I am missing out?

```
.overflowY { overflow-y: hidden !important;}
.ms-core-overlay .overflowY { overflow-y: hidden !important;}
```

When I use the `#s4-workspace {}` then it hides the scroll page of the whole page instead of the page-viewer within the form. Maybe I am supposed to use `#s4-workspace .overflowY {}` ...?

UPDATE:

Inspecting it further, I noticed the iframe section as the added custom css section is also there ... although, something else is overwriting it.

[image]

Comment: did you try #s4-workspace.overflowY { overflow-y: hidden !important; } ?

you cant overwrite an #id with just a .class

Comment: Learn about css [specificity and order](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) and then you shouldn't need to use `!important` too - by the looks it has been overused which is why you are having a css nightmare

Answer (score 1):

This selector...

```
.ms-core-overlay .overflowY
```

... matches any element with class 'overflowY', which is a *descendant* of any element with class 'ms-core-overlay'. Remember, whitespace is meaningful in CSS.

What you actually should write is...

```
.ms-core-overlay.overflowY
```

... that selects any element that has both classes applied to it. And yes, specificity of this selector is higher than specificity of `.overflowY` one: two classes weight more than one, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn about css specificity and order and perhaps selectors.  To answer your question.

Your first selector

```
.overflowY { overflow-y: hidden !important; }
```

Will only work if it is included **after** the original selector of

```
.overflowY { overflow-y: scroll !important; }
```

**Example of order:**

```css
.overflowY {
  height:100px;
  overflow:scroll !important;
}
.inner {
  height: 1000px
}

/* as this is included after and has same specificity, it should override any previous */
.overflowY {
  overflow:hidden !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="overflowY">
  <div class="inner">should have no scrollbar</div>
</div>
```

Your second selector is wrong - you are saying overflowY is a child of ms-core-overlay, you would need to change this to

```
.ms-core-overlay.overflowY { overflow-y: hidden !important;}
```

By removing the space, you are saying an element with both classes and as 2 classes is more specific than one class, then this should also overwrite the original

**Example of specificity**

```css
/* as this is more specific (ie 2 classes vs 1 class) order does not matter */
.another-class.overflowY {
  overflow:hidden !important;
}

.overflowY {
  height:100px;
  overflow:scroll !important;
}
.inner {
  height: 1000px
}
```

```html
<div class="another-class overflowY">
  <div class="inner">should have no scrollbar</div>
</div>
```

**More information about specificity**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: I just replaced my CSS with only single line `.ms-core-overlay.overflowY { overflow-y: hidden !important;}` and the result has not changed ...

Comment: @Bucki, then you must have other styles impeding it, please create a [MCVE] demonstrating your problem as clearly from my examples that should overwrite the original style that you have shown in your image. I would also add that your use of important rule is quite shocking, it should only be used as a last resort to overwrite any inline styles you have no control over (eg when a plugin adds them)

Comment: to elaborate this topic further: I am using Nintex to create forms whereby a an approver will have to approve a request - but the request was to also see the actual request form.  My solution was to add a `PageViewer` within Nintex which acts as an iframe but is not an actual html iframe ... never the less, with the inspector I select only that particular pageview section where I like to remove the scroller. In fact, the scroller is not causing a problem but it would make it look better without the scroller as it content is shown in full anyway and scroller is not needed. but yeh,

Comment: by the way, I only tried each css line one by one and not all in one junk :) I kind of suffer under OCD and when I like to get something done it sticks in my mind until I get it done .. hence why I been spending a lot of time trying to get that scroller off.